# Question closed as off-topic without further discussion

Tags: discussion, moderation, off-topic

About a week and a half ago I've posted a question on the Security Stack Exchange forum relative to the SMB1 protocol: [SMB1 deactivation on OSX and Linux](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160205/smb1-deactivation-on-osx-and-linux?noredirect=1#comment304786_160205)

As a long-time user of StackExchange network websites I performed due diligence to make sure that the question I was asking could not be answered by googling. However, within a day the question was put on hold, then closed as off-topic by a moderator with the reason given that the answer to that question, including a link posted in the comments was on the first page of google result.

When I tried to discuss more in depth what was going on in a chat [room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59231/discussion-between-andrei-kucharavy-and-schroeder), I received no answer and the question was closed after that.

As of now, as far as my understanding goes, am still with a vulnerable group of systems on my hand, no pointer on how to correct them and unable to ask questions about how to correct it nor having a better idea how to ask better questions in the future.

As far as my understanding of the scope of StackExchange and StackOverflow (based among others on my reading of CodingHorror and JoelOnSoftware), this is not a normal course of events.

Comment: From my reading of the comments there, it seems to have been closed as off-topic - since it is not a security question but an OS config question. I thought @Schroeder's comment made that clear - it wasn't just because it is easy to find, that part was trying to point you in the right direction.

Comment: So to be clear, this is the type of questions that should have been asked on Serverfault and AskDifferent Stackexchanges, right?

Comment: im not sure SF would welcome it, but you could try.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say you weren't given any direction - there were quite a few comments left with guidance for you.

Comment: @RoryAlsop so why SF would not welcome it? I am trying to understand what makes my question off-topic.

Comment: @RoryAlsop : RTFD are generally not considered as appropriate answers on StackOverflow (where most of my usage concentrates). Especially not when I explained that google gave me nothing and the only suggestion mod left was just to google it.

Comment: @AndreiKucharavy it's not good for SF because it's not about a server-level problem. You would want to ask on one of the Unix.SE sites or even SuperUser. Those are the places you would go to ask questions about how to change the configs of operating systems.

Comment: @AndreiKucharavy To reiterate, it's off-topic because - although you might be asking for a security reason - it's about service configuration. Hence, it's best addressed to SMB experts instead of security experts.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea if the question is answerable with a quick google or not, but I don't think that is the important part. Instead I think you should focus on the stated close reason:

> This question does not appear to be about Information security within the scope defined in the help center.

Also, with my highlight, the explanation from the moderator who closed it:

> **this is not a security question but an OS config question** - it also seems possible to find with a little bit of searching ....

It might have been a security issue that caused you to ask the question, but the question itself is more about how to configure your OS than it is about security. It's a bit unfortunate that the subsequent discussion got focused on wheater or not the answer was googable, since that is besides the point in my opinion.